# CodeIgniter accessing models from helper

Tags: codeigniter

I'm writing a CodeIgniter helper for e-mail functions, and need currently in each function I'm writing:

```
$CI = &get_instance();
$CI
->email
//etc
```

It's not a big problem, but I was wondering if there was a way of loading the CI instance once for all functions? Something like a constructor method?

Comment: Not sure if you've seen my answer but I've updated it to be safer

Comment: Helpers or just a bunch of functions, not a class. You should write a library for that, not a helper.

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely set on defining your functions inside of a helper rather than [extending CodeIgniter's email library](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html?highlight=extend%20library) then you can do this:

**email_helper.php**

```
<?php
// Assuming $CI has not been set before this point
$CI = &get_instance();

function some_email_function()
{
    $GLOBALS['CI']->email;
}

unset($CI);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this.

Here's an example

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Example {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }
    public function functionExample(){

        $this->CI->load->module('fullpage');
        if($this->CI->fullpage->my_function() ){
           echo 'It works!'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per CI's documentation, Helpers are not classes:  "Each helper file is simply a collection of functions in a particular category.... Unlike most other systems in CodeIgniter, Helpers are not written in an Object Oriented format." https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: totally agree, but you can always create a library